# How to let user save or edit his profile info in Django manually without using Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am working on a bootstrap template. but heaving problem with saving profile info in database. here is my code. i don't know if i am doing it right. but it,s not working .

## models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  Propic = models.ImageField(upload_to="Banners/", null=True,blank=True)
  bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

## views.py

```
def profile(request):
ids = request.user.id
user = User.objects.get(pk=ids)
if request.method == "POST":
    bio = request.POST["bio"]   
    location = request.POST["location"]
    image = request.FILES['pic']

    form = user.profile(bio = bio , location = location , propic=image)
    form.save() 
    return HttpResponse("info saved")

return render(request, "dashbord/user.html", {"user": user })
```

Comment: **but it,s not working .** This is not the right way to describe the problem. If you are getting any errors(or exceptions) you should post the full trace back.

Comment: Also note that using a Bootstrap template doesn't in any way prevent you from using a Django form.

Comment: What exact error are you getting ?

Comment: @a_python_user actually right now i am getting "MultiValueDictKeyError" in "pic" but i know it,s not the main problem if i remove it or solve the error there gonna be another error while saving so i am not sure if i am doing it right way. that,s why i didn't give any error in question .

Comment: @DanielRoseman but form is already built in html, css, i don't know why i need django from now. ok even if build one do i need to replace it with html,css form ? if yes i don't know how to add css to it,s every column differently. sry i am new to django

Comment: The primary point of forms is for validation. What happens if your users don't include a bio or location? What happens if they upload something that isn't an image? What happens if they enter a string that is too long for the location? The Django form will catch and deal with all those issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help guys. i figure it out how to do it. you need to save each column separately like this.

```
def profile(request , *args, **kwargs):
  ids = request.user.id
  user = User.objects.get(pk=ids)
  if request.method == "POST":  
     if "bio" in request.POST and "location" in request.POST:

        bio = request.POST["bio"]   
        location = request.POST["location"]

        user.profile.bio = bio 
        user.profile.location = location
        user.profile.save()

    elif "image" in request.FILES:

        image = request.FILES['image']  
        user.profile.Propic.save(image.name , image)

   return render(request, "dashbord/user.html", {"user": user })
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app dir create forms.py contains:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from your-app.models import Profile # insert your currently app name 

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Profile
```

and views.py:

```
from django.views import View
from your-app.models import Profile # your curr app name
from your-app.forms import ProfileForm
class UpdateProfile(View):
      model = Profile
      template_name = 'some.html'
      def get(self, request, **kwargs):
          user = Profile.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
          form = ProfileForm(initial=user.__dict__)
          return render(request, self.template_name, locals())
      def post(self, request, **kwargs):
          user = Profile.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
          os.remove(user.propic.path)
          form.ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
          form.save()
          return redirect('/')
```

and your urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = [
      ....,
      path('update', UpdateProfile.as_view()),
      ...
  ]
```

update template:

```
<form action="update/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!-- this line requered, otherwise your form won't take a photo -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form }}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel">
</form>
```

just copy past this a assume its will work